# Why is G7 chord highly unstable in C scale?

Tags: chords, scales

Why is G7 chord highly unstable in C scale ?

Comment: How is it unstable?

Comment: Please elaborate on how the G7 chord is unstable in the C scale.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know where you read this term "highly unstable", but what you are referring to is its function in a *chord progression*. In the key of C major, G7 is the *dominant seventh* chord, meaning that it has a particular function. In music theory, the dominant seventh chord appears at the point of the musical phrase that has the most musical *tension*. After the appearance of this chord,  the music has a strong *tendency* to want to *resolve* itself by being followed by the *tonic* chord. In the key of C major, the tonic chord is the C major chord.

So music written in any major key, or any minor key, has a tonic chord and a dominant chord and they have specific functions.

Answer (score 8):

It's because of the dissonant tritone interval B-F that wants to resolve. The B leads to the C (root) and the F leads to the E (major third of the C major triad).

This is the traditional view. Note that e.g. in the blues, a dominant seventh chord is not considered unstable; it's used as the basic chord on the I, IV, and V.